# How can I install GNOME 3.1.0 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: gnome, kernel, security

I have been with Linux since 2011 and loved fedora 16 with 3.1.0 Gnome. It was one of the best distros imo. It was very resource-efficient.

When that fedora version came to EOL I migrated to Ubuntu 14.04 as it was still better than the versions of GNOME used in later versions of fedora. Now as we know Ubuntu is about to migrate to GNOME. So I would like to have my old 3.1.0 Gnome back on newer kernel and a newer version of Ubuntu (or fedora).

I am not a pro and this thought came across my mind; if I install the good old fedora 16 and upgrade its kernel to the latest, will my GNOME be the same and security risks minimized as in the latest one? I mean I want to use that specific GNOME 3.1.0 and I am concerned about the security risks. I am ok with outdated packages and so on if they are secure.

Comment: This question is likely *off-topic* as you appear to be asking a question about running Fedora 16 (which is not Ubuntu). A better place for this question would be Stack Exchange's Unix & Linux Q&A site.  Regardless GNOME 3.1 requires the software stack used also be the same, so your GLib/GTK+ would have to be the same 3.1, requiring all apps be compatible (ie. old versions) otherwise APIs won't match... Result is a complicated mess, and potential security-risk.

Comment: i would love to try gnome 3.1.0 on latest ubuntu as well. migration to fedora is not i want to. i just want to know how to get gnome 3.1.0. and is it safe?

Comment: You would have to use the gnome apps that came with 3.1; ie. you'd be really old application programs (really old browsers, mail programs), and the old version of chrome/firefox that ran on 3.1 would not be safe today. **I really don't know, but I'd bet not.**   (API=application program interface, how gnome would speak to Glib, speak to GTK+ etc and they all have to be the same version, so your libs [libraries] must be old to run GNOME 3.1)

Comment: Voted to close because of "if i install the good old fedora 16 and upgrade it's kernel to latest, will my gnome be same and security risks minimized to the latest one?"

Comment: Voting to close: Ubuntu 16.04 ships with Gnome 3.14. That's the version of Gnome supported here for that particular release of Ubuntu. Users can install any version of Gnome they wish on 16.04, but they are on their own - it won't be supported here.

Answer (score 1):

Even Ubuntu 12.04 LTS has GNOME 3.4.2, so you can't get the GNOME version that you want. And all userspace apps are changed, systemd came and so on.

But if you need a classic desktop experience without bells and whistles you should try [MATE DE](http://mate-desktop.org/):

- Install [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS MATE](http://ubuntu-mate.org/download/)

or

- Install normal Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^`.